# How do I determine when the compiler is caching values and not reading them from the proper registers or memory locations?

Tags: c, arm

I am running into a problem where I am polling flags in an ARM processor for SPI transmission completion and it hangs in the while loop. I am not entirely sure what is going on and I suspect that the compiler is not actually fetching the value stored in the register.

```
//LPSPI1 is part of the ARM CMSIS ABI

void WriteCmdDataLCD(uint8_t *data_buffer, uint32_t data_length)
{
volatile uint32_t inc = 0;
...
while(inc < data_length)
{
    LPSPI1->TDR = *(data_buffer+inc);
    while(((LPSPI1->SR & LPSPI_SR_TDF_MASK) >> LPSPI_SR_TDF_SHIFT) == 0);
    LPSPI1->SR = LPSPI_SR_TDF_MASK;
    inc++;

}
...
```

The LPSPI1 TX FIFO is 16 words deep, if I write 16 words or less to this FIFO there is no problem. However, when I write more than 16 then it gets stuck in that while loop. Presumably because TDF (Transmission Done Flag) never evaluates to 1 (for complete). The debugger is too invasive because if I break program execution and restart it, it gets beyond that point.

***ICACHE and DCACHE*** are disabled. I am at a loss for next steps.

If it matters, the ARM processor is the I.MXRT1060.

Edit:
So this is a phantom problem and is hardware behavior related. I need to rethink how to use this peripheral.

Comment: `*(data_buffer+inc)` => `data_buffer[inc]` more readable this way

Comment: my two cents: try find some ways to debug this, to see what is actually going on. I don't know what device you are using, but on Arduino for instance you can write to serial, or worst comes to shove you can turn on/of some leds.

Comment: If `LPSP11` is part of the ABI, I'd expect it to be declared volatile in the appropriate header.

Comment: It is not useful to declare `inc` to be `volatile` when in fact its value is *not* subject to changes independent of the program's C semantics.

Comment: You could look at the assembly generated by your compiler to see if there really is a load inside the loop.  Also, check the system headers to see whether `LPSPI1` and its members are declared `volatile` as they should be.

Comment: @NateEldredge LPSPI1 is part of the CMSIS ABI which is developed by ARM, I comfortable in saying without verification that its declared the way it needs to be. Any problems with it would have been seen by others way before me. Looking at the assembly is the only way to really be sure to verify what the compiler is doing. My question is "How to determine" but without looking at the assembly. In other words, lazy.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I determine when the compiler is caching values

The compiler is not caching anything (maybe something internal when the compiler is run) The hardware when you run the compiled program might cache something.

> ICACHE and DCACHE are disabled. I am at a loss for next steps.

Then nothing will be cached and your problem simply does not exist. But even if you enable them Cortex-M7 guarantees that the core accesses to the memory is coherent. In your case, you poll for the data and core reads (and writes) hardware registers and memory.

If you use DMA with the cache ON - you will have to invalidate the cache before accessing the data. But it is not the case here.

There is a lot of confusion about the volatile in this question and answers.

To clarify:

1. `volatile uint32_t inc = 0;` - `inc` does not have to be volatile.
2. Hardware registers are declared as volatile in the NXP provided headers. Nothing to worry about. Those headers are used by thousands of programmers around the world.
3. data buffers do not have to be volatile.

Your check can be simplified to:

`while(!(LPSPI1->SR & LPSPI_SR_TDF_MASK));`

The data register write is incorrect. It shuld be:

```
*(volatile uint8_t *)&LPSPI1->TDR = *(data_buffer+inc);
```

otherwise, the compiler will generate 32 bit write instruction and 4 values will be stored in the FIFO instead of one (your data + 3 zero bytes). It is a very common beginners trap. Here you can see the difference in the generated code: https://godbolt.org/z/x9Knd5

The order of operation is incorrect (you should first check if you can write, then write) it shuld be:

```
while(!(LPSPI1->SR & LPSPI_SR_TDF_MASK));
*(volatile uint8_t *)&LPSPI1->TDR = *(data_buffer+inc);
```

The question of why it stops in the `while` loop is almost impossible to answer without the full code and access to your hardware. I can only guess. Probably the peripheral is not correctly configured and/or some error conditions are detected. You never check the error flags.

> Presumably because TDF (Transmission Done Flag)
> It is `Transmit Data Flag` and it does not indicate the end of the transmission.

There is another flag called `TCF` used to indicate the end of the transfer. **I strongly advise to read carefully and with understanding the relevant chapter of the `Referance Manual`, then start to write the software**

Comment: I have been up and down the RM Chapt 48, tho I do learn something new every time. My main concern was whether or not the compiler would cache a value in a reg..say R2 and then continue to test that value and not fetch a new value on the next loop iteration. From my understanding that's what 'volatile' "prevents". The RM states that there is a request for data when the FIFO cnt is <= to the TXWATER in FCR Reg. It's set to 0 in my case, so my use is technically valid. Before I posted here, did come across a timing issue with the peripheral and inst execution.

Comment: I know that my declaration of inc as volatile is superfluous but ultimately its just distracting and not the subject of question. When I enter into the loop I have already made the initial check to see if its safe to write to TDR, through the same loop type check. I looked at the godbolt link your provided. Thank you. I do not believe its going to matter, STR vs STRB.

Comment: @MadVocoder42 `do not believe its going to matter` you can believe in anything you want.

Comment: I forgot about another nonsense `LPSPI1->SR = LPSPI_SR_TDF_MASK;`

Comment: There are a few flags (that wasn't one of them) that are W1C (write once to clear) and my intent was to clear it, but that wasn't one of the W1C flags. So nonsense? Not really, but is unnecessary.

Comment: @MadVocoder42 nonsense. What did you want to archieve  with it?

Answer (score -3):

> How do I determine when the compiler is caching values and not reading
> them from the proper registers or memory locations?

The compiler might want to "cache" all values which are not declared with ***volatile***.

You might create a test:

```
unsigned int maybe_cached = REGISTER;
volatile unsigned int never_cached = REGISTER;

/* some code */

if(maybe_cached != never_cached){
    /* something had been cached */
}
```

PS you should use ***volatile*** at atleast for all asynchronous operations.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you explained which variable he needs to declare `volatile`. He used this with `inc`, but it's the data buffer that needs to be volatile.

Comment: It does not make any sense in this case.

Comment: It's for debugging. OP may use this code to determine which variables are asynchronous.